# keep variables of file included via ob_start(); ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean();

Tags: php, file, include

I include templates via ob_start(); ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); If I use normal html code it works fine. Now I want to collect the content via variables. Like so:

```
position_right_top = explode(':',$this -> out['position']);

    $oskar_arr[$this -> out['bereich']][$this -> out['ggf__tabellenzeile']] = "<div class=Das \"oskar\" style=\"top: ".$position_right_top[0]."px; right: ".$position_right_top[1]."px;\">

      <div class=\"oskar-inner\">

        ".$this -> out['bildoskar']."

        <div class=\"oskar-text\">".$this -> out['texthinweis']."</div>

      </div>

    </div>";
```

Then I want to output the array variable in another template included like so:

```
echo $oskar_arr[$template_for_oskar][$this -> row_text_id];
```

```
ob_start();
                      include './templates/'.$format.'/template/'.$format.'.php';
                      $template_content .= ob_get_contents();
                      ob_end_clean();
```

So how can I transfer or keep the variable for the further inlucded templates? Any tipp is welcome.

Comment: The local scope persists after the include(). Else [`get_defined_vars()`](http://php.net/get_defined_vars) to collect them.

Comment: the problem has an other reason, thanks anyway for you tipp